# Ruby generators vs Python generators

Tags: python, ruby, generator, enumerator

I've been researching the similarities/differences between Ruby and Python generators (known as `Enumerators` in Ruby), and so far as i can tell they're pretty much equivalent.

However one difference i've noticed is that Python Generators support a `close()` method whereas Ruby Generators do not. From the Python docs the `close()` method is said to do the following:

> Raises a GeneratorExit at the point where the generator function was paused. If the generator function then raises StopIteration (by exiting normally, or due to already being closed) or GeneratorExit (by not catching the exception), close returns to its caller."

Is there a good reason why Ruby `Enumerators` don't support the `close()` method? Or is it an accidental 
omission?

I also discovered that Ruby `Enumerators` support a `rewind()` method yet Python generators do not...is there a reason for this too?

Thanks

Comment: Curious, but I don't understand how you'd use this: can you give an example?

Comment: @Andrew Vit: this can be used to cause resources —database connections, files, etc.— held by the generator to be cleaned up.  It will also prevent any further calls to its `next` or `send` methods from other parts of the code.  You could call `close`, for example, to indicate from one of a number of consumers to indicate to others that a desired value has been found.

Comment: @intuited, is Python's `close()` actually commonly used though? I think i read somewhere that it's considered 'arcane' by the python community and not really utilized.

Comment: `close()` is part of the API for carrying out two-way communication with the generator, turning it into a "co-routine". You can read about it in http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/. Does Ruby have that concept?

Answer (score 7):

This [documentation for the rewind method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/generator/rdoc/Generator.html#method-i-rewind) is a little scarce on details.  But in order to "start over" the generator would have to do one of two things:

- remember its complete output, repeat that output once rewound, then resume what it was doing before
- reset its internal state in a way that causes the same output to be repeated without other unwanted side effects

The second of these is not always possible; for example, if the generator emits byte buffers from the network, the output is not entirely a function of internal state.  But any generator that uses the first technique must necessarily build up a larger and larger buffer in memory as it is used.  Such generators offer little performance benefit over lists.

Therefore, I conclude that the Ruby `rewind` method must be optional and not always supported by a concrete enumerator class.  So if the Python designers value the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), that would lead them not to require such a method in all generators.

Answer (score 2):

Generators are stack based, Ruby's Enumerators are *often* specialised (at the interpreter level) and not stack based.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's Enumerator's use StopIteration class internally, see [How do Enumerators work in Ruby 1.9.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436037/how-do-enumerators-work-in-ruby-1-9-1)

(it's just wrapped if you use it in a for each call).  So I'd say they'are a rather close.  That being said, I'm not sure what a close method on an enumerator *should* do, exactly...cleanup, perhaps?  (Python's generators probably would benefit from a rewind--note well that in Ruby, some enumerators don't respond to rewind, so they raise an exception when you call that method).

Comment: thanks for your answer. But `StopIteration` is what python uses too - in fact Ruby took this idea from Python hehe. As Regards what a `close()` might do, look to intuited's comment to my question (above).

Comment: yeah ruby 1.9.x's Enumerator basically brought it into line with Python's Generator (though you can also just use a block in Ruby to simulate a generator, really).